# My HTML or CSS prevents me from scrolling down on mobile sized screens

Tags: html, css, scroll, responsive-design

The title pretty much says what my issue is. I did a few google searches and couldn't find anything helpful so I came here. Here is the link to the site: https://aquamarine-catharina-45.tiiny.site/

I changed from ".container" having the properties: position: fixed; and left: 35% to just margin-left: 35% thinking that may fix it but it didn't.

edit: Pay no attention to the second page I've already fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the overflow-y property of the html element to hidden. Change it to visible.

```
html{
overflow-y: visible;
}
```

Comment: This did it. Ironically I put that in there as a potential solution to this problem I got from somewhere else and just forgot about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use overflow-y: auto. Depending on what section you want to scroll down you can put the overflow on. You can use it either on the body or in the container.

```
body {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

or

```
.container {
   width: 90%;
   margin-left: 5%;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```